# Entity Framework Core 2.1 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Type Flag is not a defined system type

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-migrations

After upgrading to EntityFramework 2.1.11, I am facing the following issue.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Type Flag is not a defined system type.
```

I am getting this Error for Linq to SQL internal translation. There are two columns in database table which are of tinyint datatype which have corresponding C# datatype as byte, which is throwing exception in Linq while querying.

The reason is `column == 1`   is translated as `CAST(1 AS Flag)`internally in 2.1 which was working in 2.0.

It is working if we `change == 1` to `== Convert.ToByte(1)` or assigning to byte variable and using that as `==` variable which I think is not the ideal fix.

This is the piece of code which is throwing error.

```
    var query = await (from pl in _azureContext.Product.AsNoTracking()
    where pl.Primary ==1 &&  pl.Deleted == 0
    select new Product
    {
      ProductId = pl.ProductId,
      ProductName = pl.ProductName
    }).OrderBy(P => P.ProductName).ToListAsync<Product>();
```

SQL Internal Translation which throws exception is as follows:

```
SELECT  [pl].[ProductId] , [pl].[ProductName] FROM [Products] AS [pl] WHERE ([pl].[Primary] = CAST(1 AS Flag)) AND ([pl].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS Flag)) ORDER BY [pl].[ProductName]
```

The Expected SQL Translation is as follows:

```
SELECT  [pl].[ProductId] , [pl].[ProductName] FROM [Products] AS [pl] WHERE ([pl].[Primary] = 1) AND ([pl].[Deleted] = 0) ORDER BY [pl].[ProductName]
```

It looks like a bug in Entityframework Core 2.1. Could anyone please help me on this?

Added additional information based on comments from David.
1) I haven't created any custom type for this and not missing. 
2) C# datat type is Byte for pl.Primary and pl.Deleted. 
3) In the dbContext I am seeing the following in onModelCreating method. 
    entity.Property(e => e.Primary).HasColumnType("Flag"); 
    entity.Property(e => e.Deleted).HasColumnType("Flag");

Note: DbContext was generated earlier with .net core 2.0 and no code changes done on that.

Comment: Firstly, please take care of your post formatting next time. Secondly, I cannot understand your Linq query at all, perhaps because your formatting was so messed up.

Comment: Modified now, Could you please check now. There was an issue in formatting earlier. The issue is if a column is tinyint and in linq if uses ==1, it translates to CAST(1 AS Flag) internally in SQL generated.

Comment: You have now broken the formatting (that I already fixed for you) and still not fixed the Linq code that cannot possibly compile. Since you are unwilling to expend any effort, then I am unwilling to help you I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidG, Thank you for your support. Updated the Question, corrected formatting. and modified the code.

Comment: OK, now we are getting somewhere. So have you created a custom SQL type that you are missing? What C# type are `pl.Primary` and `pl.Deleted`? What SQL type are they? Can you show your `DbContext` configuration for these too?

Comment: Thank you @DavidG. Both columns are of SQL type tinyint. The above code was working in EntityFramework Core 2.0. Once upgraded it started breaking.

Comment: You have answered 1 of the 3 questions I asked, it's not enough. **Please** demonstrate more effort.

Comment: @DavidG, thank you for your valuable response. Sorry for not  providing all information. For your other questions, PFA the details 1)So have you created a custom SQL type that you are missing? No. I haven't created any custom type for this and not missing. 2)What C# type are pl.Primary and pl.Deleted? Byte.  In the dbContext I am seeing the following in onModelCreating method.      
    entity.Property(e => e.Primary).HasColumnType("Flag");    entity.Property(e => e.Deleted).HasColumnType("Flag"); Note: DbContext was generated earlier with .net core 2.0 and no code changes done on that.

Comment: You should [edit] this information into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have `HasColumnType("Flag")` in the configuration for your properties. This tells Entity Framework that the type of the column is `Flag`, obviously not a standard SQL Server data type. The simple solution is to remove that configuration method.

However, those columns are obviously meant to be boolean flags, and you should be using the appropriate data type. This means in C# your type is `bool` and in SQL Server it is `bit`. For example, your table would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    -- Other columns
    Primary BIT,
    Deleted BIT
)
```

and your C# class like this

```cs
public class Product
{
    // Snip other columns
    public bool Primary { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The table concerned is in Production and the dbcontext was auto generated with 2.0  earlier and was working property.  After upgrading only I am getting this issue. Could you please let me know is there any major change in 2.1 which is causing this behavior? Or the 2.0 code generation had an issue and that got fixed now?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no change that could have affected you here. I cannot even see how it worked previously, unless you had a [SQL type alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-user-defined-data-type-alias?view=sql-server-2017) (for example `CREATE TYPE Flag  
FROM int`) that no longer exists.

Comment: Manually modifying .HasColumnType("Flag") to .HasColumnType("tinyint") works for me(not the ideal fix). Not sure why scaffolding creates .HasColumnType("Flag") for tinyint in .Net Core 2.0 as well as .Net Core 2.1

Comment: Identified the issue.. 

dbcontext was generated on onpremise db. It earlier migrated to azure with connection string update by dev. While upgrading to EF Core 2.1 we got the issue. Found few user defined datatypes like Flag of type tinyint etc were not present in the Azure Instance.
2.0 it was working as the the query filter x.Primary == 1 was translated as x.Primary = 1 even though the .HasColumnType("Flag") was there in the configuration.
In 2.1 it is translated as x.Primary = CAST(1 AS Flag) using the.HasColumnType("Flag") in the configuration.
Thank you for all your support.